# Regex to exclude some directories inside one directory

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am reading directories inside one directory. It has names like abcModule and abcRelationModule, xyzModule

I have this regex `modules/*/graphql-schema` but it is considering `abcModule`, `abcRelationModule`, `xyzModule`.

I want to exclude `abcRelationModule`, which have `RelationModule` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
modules\/(?![^\/]*RelationModule)[^\/]*\/graphql-schema
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BbTBNF/1)**

**[See the JAVA code here](https://regex101.com/r/BbTBNF/1/codegen?language=java)**

**Explanation:**

- `modules\/` - matches `modules/` literally
- `(?![^\/]*RelationModule)` - negative lookahead to check if the the text `RelationModule` is present anywhere before the occurrence of next `/` in the directory
- `[^\/]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except `/`
- `\/graphql-schema` - matches `/graphql-schema` literally

If you do not want `RelationModule` anywhere in the directory, you can simply use [`^(?!.*RelationModule).+$`](https://regex101.com/r/BbTBNF/2)